# Request Azure OAuth 2.0 Token unable to generate

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to generate access token by hitting the following link:

```
       {https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx-def2-4558-93fc-9b8f44aaf78a/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
       client_id=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-8f83-f5dc90ec4f74
       &response_type=code
       &redirect_uri=https://xxxx-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger2
       &response_mode=query
       &scope=User.Read
       &state=12345
     &code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGYyM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl
      &code_challenge_method=plain
```

}

but in a response i got request code instead of token.
i am using the following Code in HTTP Trigger

```
  var resultcode;
  module.exports=async function(context,req){ 
  context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
  const code = (req.query.code || (req.code && req.body.code));
  resultcode=code;
  context.res = generatetoken(context,resultcode);
  context.done();
     }
  function generatetoken(context,rescode){
  var request = require('request');
  var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  'headers': {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded'
  },
  form: {
 'client_id': '79c9a036-42e5-407d-8f83-f5dc90ec4f74',
 'code': rescode,
 'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost/myapp/',
 'grant_type': 'Authorization_Code',
 'client_secret': 'W-ie3QlV-_O084H.0U8R2E3bfr_Aun5j_T'
  }
  };
 request(options, function (error, response) {
 if (error) throw new Error(error);
 console.log("response.body");
 context.res={
  body:response
 }
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use [Auth code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the access token. The steps of Auth code grant flow is request an authorization code first, and then request for the access token.

First step: [Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) is what you did with the link you provided at the beginning of your question. It will redirect to a url with with "code=xxxxx". You need to get the `code`.

Next step: [Request for access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) with the `code` which you got above. Please refer to the screenshot below, the screenshot is what I request for access token with "code". You just need to implement the request below in your function code.
[image]

==================================**Update**===========================

Below is my function code for your reference:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var resultcode;
    resultcode="0.ARoATqxxxxxxxxxxVtwgAA";
    context.res = generatetoken(context,resultcode);
    context.res = {
        body: "success"
    };
}

function generatetoken(context,rescode){
    var request = require('request');
    var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9xxxxxxxxba2a757fb/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
   'client_id': '7a6f7xxxxxxxxxxfd79e9',
   'code': rescode,
   'redirect_uri': 'https://hurytest',
   'grant_type': 'Authorization_Code',
   'scope': 'openid https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
   'client_secret': '2Wjp2xxxxxxxxxxxxXdq4Qckdi'
    }
    };
   request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
    context.res={
        body:response
    }
   });
}
```

The code above can console the access token success as below screenshot show:
[image]

=============================**Update 2**======================

If you want the token shown in the response of the function, please refer to my code:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var resultcode;
    resultcode="0.ARoATqvJ5Cxxxxxxxxxxv5wiH9RSQ0gAA";
    var result = await generatetoken(context,resultcode);
    context.res = {
        body: result
    };
}

function generatetoken(context,rescode){
    var request = require('request');
   
    var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9xxxxxxxxxxxx57fb/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
   'client_id': '7a6fxxxxxxxxxxxxxfd79e9',
   'code': rescode,
   'redirect_uri': 'https://hurytest',
   'grant_type': 'Authorization_Code',
   'scope': 'openid https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
   'client_secret': '2WjpxxxxxxxxxxxQckdi'
    }
    };
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
            reject(err);
            } else {
            resolve(res.body);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually i tried it by postman i got token but unfortunately token is not generated through nodejs function when i coded above

Comment: @AhmadRehman May I know what's the error message in the response of your code ?

Comment: @AhmadRehman Did you missing `scope` in the `form: {` of your code ?

Comment: when i remove generatetoken() function got  code in response but when call this function then i got empty response

Comment: @AhmadRehman I will do some test, please wait a moment.

Comment: Hi @AhmadRehman Please refer to the update of my answer.

Comment: @AhmadRehman Have you solved the problem ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: @AhmadRehman If you also want the access token shown in the response of function, please refer to "Update 2" of my answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy you are hero i am trying to follow the code as you mentioned in a screenshot then i will let you know asap thanks

Comment: Actually you put request code explicitly i want some thing like request code is generate inside in a function then (in response of request code) token is generated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226922/discussion-between-ahmad-rehman-and-hury-shen).

Comment: @AhmadRehman Sorry for delay. In first "Update" of my answer, the code console.log the token explicitly. But in "Update 2" of my answer, the token was generated in the response of the function. Does this meet your requirement ?

Comment: i am talking about Authorization code which you store in variable (you named it 'resultcode'  ) and then on the basis of this resultcode you generate token. my requirement is that the authorization code(resultcode) generate itself and then i assign it to var resultcode programmatically just like i did in a question code snap.

Comment: @AhmadRehman I don't think we can generate the authorization code easily in function because it needs another request(as the first part of code you provided), it will redirect to another page and we also need to input username and password. So we can't do it programmatically in function. What we can do is as the second part of code you provided, get it from `req.query.code`.

Comment: may be you are right but how i can implement this on Flutter actually i want authentication through mobile application

Comment: @AhmadRehman You can specify the `redirect_uri` of the app registered in Azure AD with the url of the function. Then when the grant flow complete first step to get authorization code, it will redirect to your function url with `?code=xxx` follow the function url (like `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=xxxxx`). Then you can get the code in your function.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this issue by the following method 1.create a HTTP Trigger function and generate token silently. by posting the following request

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx-xxxx-4558-xxxx- 
xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=79c9xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f5dc90ec4f74
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=https://xxxx-client.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger2
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=User.Read
&state=12345
&code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGY
yM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl
&code_challenge_method=plain
```

and the following below function:

```
   module.exports=async function(context,req){ 
   context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
   const code = (req.query.code || (req.code && req.body.code));
   context.res= {
   body:code  
  };
    }
```